# Selectively disable automation cases per environment

Tags: java, jenkins, automation, testng

**What I am doing**: Using Jenkins to run the same test suites and test cases against various environments - dev / staging / production. I'm using WebDriver with a Java implementation and TestNG.

**What I'd like to do**: Selectively disable *some* tests, but not entire test suites, from running *depending* on the environment. Rather than maintain separate codebases between environments, I'd like to know of a way to accomplish this.

**Initial thoughts**: I was thinking setting a system property in Jenkins for each job in each environment and each test decorator would have to pull this piece of information out to determine if it should be ran or not. I think it's clunky, I'm not sure how to do it, and I'm not sure if this is the right approach.

Can someone tell me the best way to accomplish this? I'm hoping this isn't the best way.

Thanks,

Joe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at TestNG listeners?

You can write a listener which just before the berfore test suite is run BUT after the tests to run have been identifier, to iterate around the list of tests and remove tests you do not want to run.
Because this is programatic you can write any java to achieve what you want.

Also, you could create annotations to identify which tests run in which environment; e.g annotate those tests with something like @RunInEnvironment({"UAT", INT"});  Your listener could then use those annotations to remove tests from the list which are not required.

Comment: I like this approach. I may toy with this later today with @DontRunIn({"PROD"}); for some tests.

Answer (score 0):

I think that groups is your answer.  With TestNG you can include/exclude groups.  You will just need to define which tests are in which groups.

http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#exclusions

Comment: Excluding groups need to be set before runtime. It was a good suggestion, but I'm not sure this is the proper application for it.

Answer (score 0):

@MrTi this solution is rather static and I believe he wants more dynamicity.

If detecting your environment can be done at startup, you may be able to try one of the solution described in [that thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/testng-users/4PQ41L9y8Yk). This framework might be useful as well: https://github.com/wolfs/testng-rules

Note: on JUnit you would use Rules https://github.com/lacostej/web-validators/commit/2e1af8e1d9d1bf206849702d4231961563457815 (implementation uses old API)